# Why / How was the Constable badge awarded in Jan '18 to an MSO user?

Tags: bug, badges

The constable badge is described on the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) as:

> Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

It appears this badge was [awarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/constable) in January 2018:

[image: The award history for the 'Constable' badge]

I don't think this is a side-effect of the MSO/MSE split as the split happened much earlier. So, what happened here? By my understanding it shouldn't be possible to have this badge on MSO!

Comment: Quote from profile: "Before that I worked in AdTech at StackOverflow".  Employees usually get moderator privileges.

Comment: @HansPassant [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded?tab=profile) is also a former employee and didn't receive that badge, neither on MSE, SO or MSO. You might be on the right track there, but I wonder why other employees didn't get the badge as well.

Comment: Even more strange is that he didn't even receive the badge on the main site!

Comment: @Ḿűỻịgǻṇạcểơửṩ Stack Exchange policy is, as I understand it, to limit the scope of moderator privileges granted to employees. If it is allowed by the software, it would make sense to give certain employees mod privileges on Meta SO to allow them to do things like mark bug reports as completed. However, they don’t need moderator privileges on SO main, so they weren’t granted there.

Comment: Regarding the “pro-tem” status, I think this was a bug in how mod privileges were granted to certain employees. I distinctly remember seeing a discussion about it here or on MSE, but don’t have a link handy at the moment. Oded is not a good counter-example, as he was a *developer*, and was hired earlier.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, he was the only ex-employee I remembered :D